Map induced by the kronecker product in cyclic theory is not an isomorphism in the case of vector spaces
I was going through Loday's book on Cyclic homology. Let $k$ be a commutative ring and $A$ be an algebra over $k$. In 1.5.9, the author defines a pairing called the Kronecker product :
In particular, taking $M = A^* = Hom(A, k)$ and $M' = A$, one obtains a map
$HH^n(A) \otimes HH_n(A) \longrightarrow A^* \otimes_{A^e} A$ which when composed with the evaluation map $A^* \otimes_{A^e} A \longrightarrow k$ gives a map $HH^n(A) \otimes HH_n(A) \longrightarrow k$. Hence, there is a map $HH^n(A) \longrightarrow Hom(HH_n(A), k)$ relating the Hochschild cohomology of $A$ with the dual of Hochschild homology of $A$.
In particular, if the $k$-algebra $A$ is projective as a $k$-module, one obtains the following split exact sequence

If $k$ is a field, then $A$ is always projective as a $k$-vector space. Further, the Ext in the above split exact sequence vanishes, which means that the map $HH^n(A) \longrightarrow Hom(HH_n(A), k)$ is an isomorphism (for any field $k$ and ANY $k$-algebra $A$).
Continuing with $k$ being any commutative ring and $A$ and $k$-algebra, in 2.4.8, the author extends the kronecker product to the cyclic theory. As in the Hochschild case, this canonically induces a map in the cyclic theory $HC^n(A) \longrightarrow Hom(HC_n(A), k).

However, the author comments that this map is sometimes an isomorphism. In particular, the author says that if $k$ is a field and the $k$-algebra $A$ is \textbf{finite dimensional} as a $k$-vector space, then the map is an isomorphism. I need help in understanding why is this map in the cyclic case not always an isomorphism for ANY $k$-algebra $A$ ?
In particular, how is the finite dimension assumption crucial ? Does one "somehow" need to use the fact \textbf{that finite coproducts are the same as finite products in any additive category} in the proof ?
